# How to Install Windows Service with Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I have created an Winform application which is used to manage Book information and Generate Invoice now there is a Database function in Application which is called in every 6 days,but this function will work only when application is running.
So i have created a windows service for this, 
Now i want to know how to i deploy my windows service with my windows application.
Thanks !!!!

Comment: Before asking question, did you try searching "install windows service" on SO?

Comment: @SevaTitov  ok here is the situation
i know how to install Windows service on My Pc , Now i want to Create a Packeg of my Winform application and Windows Service for my client so that it can install with Single setup file

Comment: @Mickey have solved the problem, here is not a proper solution for it.

Answer (score -1):

You must use the installutil utility

> installutil  (e.g installutil C:\MyService.exe)

From MSDN:

> To install a Windows service On the Start menu or Start Page, open the
>   shortcut menu for Developer Command Prompt, and then choose Run As
>   Administrator. Navigate to the folder that contains your project's
>   output. For example, under your My Documents folder, navigate to
>   Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyNewService\bin\Debug. Enter the
>   following command: installutil.exe MyNewService.exe If the service
>   installs successfully, installutil.exe will report success.

Then go to Start --> Execute and type:

> services.msc

Check that your service was succesfully installed and set it's startup type (auto, manual...)

Answer (score -1):

You can create an Installer for the service and install along with your main application. You can see more here:

[How to create a setup project for a Windows Service application in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169)

Answer (score -1):

here is a link that shows you how to install windows services

[install windows service](http://www.csharp-examples.net/install-net-service/)

you have make sure you run command prompt as Administrator and choose the correct version of .netFramework and if it is a 64 bit or 32 bit application

Comment: Thanks for the reply !!
but I need to deploy my windows service with my winform application.
I need only one setup (.exe) file  for both ( actually my windows service using my winform application database for Database backup ).